# O que há de errado neste meu código do MySQL?

Tags: sql

O erro é este: error code 1064. You have a error in your sql syntax;

O meu código é este:

```
INSERT INTO pessoa (Endereço, Email, Telefone)
VALUES ('Rua Ernesta de Oliveira Pina', 'gansoprofessional@outlook.com',
'(62) 1234-5678') WHERE PS_NOME='Átila o Encapuzado'
```

Answer (score 7):

Quando você usa o INSERT no MySQL não pode usar a clausula WHERE, nem precisa, pois o WHERE é pra selecionar resultados, e o INSERT nao mexe com resultados, ele apenas cria uma nova linha (ou tupla) na tabela.

Seu codigo ficaria:

```
Insert into pessoa (Endereço, Email, Telefone) values ('Rua Ernesta de Oliveira Pina', 'gansoprofessional@outlook.com', '(62) 1234-5678')
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/485062/3473971

EDIT

Se voce quer inserir esses dados na linha determinada, na verdade voce esta fazendo um UPDATE, e nao um INSERT.

```
UPDATE pessoa SET (Endereço='xxxx', Email='ccccc', Telefone='21312321') WHERE nome='Atila blablal'
```

Algo nessas linhas, dai vc precisa adaptar pro que voce precisa.

Fonte no SQL UPDATE: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp